# Adding a new line to text string with jquery .text() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I do:

```
function testtext()
{
    var text = "test line 1\n\
    test line 2"
    ;
    $("#divtext").text(text);   
}
```

It all appears on one line. When I do:

```
function testtext()
{
    var text = "test line 1\n\
    test line 2"
    ;
    document.getElementById("divtext").innerText = text;    
}
```

It works fine...

Comment: what is your question?? or issue

Comment: What about if you set the `textContent` property ?

Comment: Well a new line in HTML is created using the `<br />` element, not a "normal" line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wondering why, it's because jQuery [creates a new text node](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L45) using `document.createTextNode`, passing your string as the argument.

This apparently behaves differently than `innerText`, though it seems to behave the same as setting `.textContent` and as explicitly setting the value of a textNode through `.nodeValue` or `.data`.

Comment: if you have few minutes can you explain me what the OP has asked?

Comment: @kobe: Near as I can tell, OP is wondering why the difference. At least that's what I'm going with on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$("#divtext").html(text);`

Instead of `$("#divtext").text(text);`

Answer (score 0):

The text() method will do an HTML escape. There are some workarounds on the API page, but perhaps the text() method isn't best suited for what you want to do?

http://api.jquery.com/text/